# Saving 'sub' from Identity Provider

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization

I need to associate `sub`, which is received as part of `$userinfo` in `openid_connect_save_userinfo`, but I don't see it as part of the claim options.  I also don't see that it's stored elsewhere.

I am using the [openid_connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_connect) project.

I'm wondering if I'm missing something in configuration and maybe I need to do something custom.

Answer (score 0):

The association is stored in `openid_connect_authmap` and there is a service: `openid_connect.authmap` to access it.

Without DI:
`\Drupal::service('openid_connect.authmap')
  ->getConnectedAccounts(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->load($userid))`